# Visualizing a picture in the tabular

Tags: tabularx, overleaf, latex3

For my thesis, I have to include my signature in the autorship page. I want to do that numerically (not hand-writing). I include the signature in the form of an image to my project and I want to put it in a tabular as follows:

```
  \noindent NAME \\ \\
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{.72in}p{3.0in}@{}}
    Signature: &  \begin{figure}[H]
\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{images/sig.png}
\end{figure}
    \\
    &\\
    Date: & 13.04.2021
\end{tabular}
```

The problem that the signaure will jump to the next line and not directly in front of the word "Signature". This is the output that I am getting:

[image]

I tried to change the floating [H] to [h], but it doesn't work.

Comment: Don't put a `figure` environment inside a `tabular`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes thanks for the answer, so how to put an image then ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented, "Don't put a `figure` (floating) environment inside a `tabular`"

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\noindent NAME \\ \\
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{.72in}p{3.0in}@{}}
    Signature: &  \includegraphics[height=30pt]{example-image}
    \\
    &\\
    Date: & 13.04.2021
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks it is working now :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a `figure` environment to include a figure/image. That might sound odd, but think of it - you're not using a `table` environment to include a `tabular`... so why do you necessarily need a `figure` environment to include an image?

Just use

```
% ...
Signature: & \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{images/sig.png} \\
% ...
```

You may have to adjust the vertical placement of `sig.png` relative to `Signature:`, but that's a minor issue. You can use `\raisebox{<height>}{<image>}` for that.

Comment: Thanks, it works :)